# how to search from specifc data in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, query-builder

let's say i have this table in database...

[image]

So i want to search from specific data, for example

- i want to search from all schedules where `station_id` is equal `1`

so I did it like this...

```
$schedule = DB::table('schedules')
                ->where('station_id', 1)
                ->where('schedule_number', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
                ->orWhere('route_name', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
                ->orWhere('user_first', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
                ->orWhere('id', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
                ->orWhere('created_at', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
                ->get();
```

But this will search from all schedules

Comment: you need to wrap your `->orWhere-s` inside `->where`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use advanced where here's documentation [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#parameter-grouping)

in your code it shouldbe like

```
  $schedule= DB::table('schedules')
                            ->where('station_id', 1)
                            ->where('schedule_number', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
                            ->where(function($q)use($query){
                                $q->where('route_name', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
                                ->orWhere('user_first', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
                                ->orWhere('id', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
                                ->orWhere('created_at', 'like', '%'.$query.'%');
                            })
                            ->get();
```

remember to pass the variable needed by place use($variable) like in my example you need to pass use($query)